# $\det( I+\Lambda UDU^*\Lambda) \le \det( I+\Lambda D\Lambda)$ for any unitary $U$, if $\Lambda$ and $D$ are real positive diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, determinant

Is it true that $\det( I+\Lambda UDU^*\Lambda) \le \det( I+\Lambda D\Lambda)$ for any unitary $U$, if $\Lambda$ and $D$ are real positive diagonal?  I tried some simple examples numerically, and it appeared so.  But not sure if this is true in general, and how to prove/refute it.

(Note that $UDU^*$ is Hermitian, and the inequality becomes an equality for any $U$ when $\Lambda=I$.  However, this is no longer true when I introduce a non-identity $\Lambda$.  Moreover, a non-identity $U$ seems to reduce the determinant. (?)  I'd like to prove/disprove it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $D$, $\Lambda$, and $U$ by

$$
D=\operatorname{diag}(1, 1, a), \qquad
\Lambda=\operatorname{diag}(1, a, 1), \qquad
U = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos t & -\sin t \\
0 & \sin t & \cos t
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $a > 0$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Then

$$ \det(1 + \Lambda U D U^* \Lambda) = 2(a+1)(a^2 + 1 + (a-1)^2 \sin^2 t) $$

This is minimized if $\sin t = 0$. So, $ t = 0 $ is a minimum point of this determinant. However, we have $U = I$ for $t = 0$. This shows that

$$ \det(1 + \Lambda U D U^* \Lambda) > \det(1 + \Lambda D \Lambda) $$

can occur.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Is there an easy way to get $ \det(1 + \Lambda U D U^* \Lambda) = 2(a+1)(a^2 + 1 + (a-1)^2 \sin^2 t) $?  Direct expansion appears tedious.

Comment: @syeh_106, Well, I cheated by using Mathematica. However, perhaps the following formula $$\det(1 + \Lambda U D U^* \Lambda)=\det(\Lambda)^2 \det(\Lambda^{-2} + U D U^*)$$ might save some labor.